# Golang for loop of certain part of map

Tags: go

Attempting to create a for loop for each part of a map.

```
map[
asn:AS10 
time:1.428790768e+09 
ipv4s:[
      68.114.75.0/24 
      216.215.56.0/22 
      216.215.60.0/22] 
ipv6s:[
      2607:f3f8::/32
]]
```

The above is the map, I'd like to try create a for loop for each value in `ipv4s`.

I've attempted, but I'm clearly not doing it correctly as it's merely based off my php knowledge.:

```
for json_map["ipv4s"]{
   //whatever       
}
```

PHP version if anyone needs an example rather then me attempting to explain:

```
foreach($obj->ipv4s as $value) {
     echo $value; // return an ip
}
```

Update

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
    )

func main() {

    response, err := http.Get("https://www.enjen.net/asn-blocklist/index.php?asn=" + os.Args[1] + "&type=json_split&api=1")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        dec := json.NewDecoder(response.Body)
        if dec == nil {
            panic("Failed to start decoding JSON data")
        }

        json_map := make(map[string]interface{})
        err = dec.Decode(&json_map)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%v\n", json_map)

        for i := range json_map {
            for _, ip := range json_map[i]["ipv4s"] {
                fmt.Printf(ip)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Whenever someone uses interface{} to get JSON data, a kitten dies. Use RawMessage http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage . 2. for i := range json_map {
            for _, ip := range json_map[i]["ipv4s"] {
                fmt.Printf(ip)
            }
        } --> madness, two loops to get one element from one map. Incredible. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) is a good source once you have completed the tutorial for go.
There it is also described how one iterates over a slice:

```
for key, value := range json_map {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you don't need the key:

```
for _, value := range json_map {
    // ...
}
```

You might have to nest two loops, if it is a slice of maps:

```
for i := range json_map {
    for _, ip := range json_map[i]["ipv4s"] {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'll take a look at effective go. One issue, i'm getting this `invalid operation: json_map[i]["ipv4s"] (type in
terface {} does not support indexing)`. I had a read over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377907/golang-issue-with-accessing-nested-json-array-after-unmarshalling yet I was unable to comprehend the answer.

Comment: Can't answer that if I don't know what struct the underlying map is.

Comment: How would I be able to find that out myself?

Comment: Well, where is the map with asn, time, ipv4s,... from and how do you insert that into go to iterate over?

Comment: https://www.enjen.net/asn-blocklist/index.php?asn=10&type=json_split&api=1 I retrieve it via a http.get. I've updated the post with complete source code.

Comment: The cleanest solution is to decode it into a struct you define (if you know what the response should look like) instead of decoding it into  `map[string]interface{}`. See http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go for example. They declare a type Message and decode the response to such a struct. Then you coud iterate over the slice, as opposed to interface{}

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with an example through my source?