# Convert *bytes.Buffer to json and Unmarshal in app engine

Tags: json, go

Having trouble decoding JSON URL GET request with golang appengine.

I'm new to golang and this is probably a simple fix.

Can't convert bytes.Buffer to struct. Am I doing it right?

Alternatively I could just query the string for the fields I want but I think that would be doing it wrong.

```
import {
"etc..."
}
.
.
// construct req.URL.String()
.
.
type Result struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
}


func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
.
.
.
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
resp, err := client.Get(req.URL.String())

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(resp.Body)

fmt.Fprintln(w, buf) // successfully prints the buffer to w and confirms successful JSON request from remote server

var MyResult []Result
json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &MyResult)

for l := range MyResult {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, MyResult[l].Type)
}

// Result: Empty...

// if I hard code the expected JSON string to a []byte array and Unmarshal I get a valid result from MyResult struct
```

Comment: What is the error returned from json.Unmarshal? Also, you can replace the code from the line where the bytes.Buffer is created to the call to json.Unmarshal with: `var MyResult []Result; err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&MyResult)`

Comment: What is the error on decode. Can you print the `string(buf.Bytes())`and error on `Unmarshal`

Comment: "What is the error returned from json.Unmarshal?" json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Result

Comment: The error indicates that you are unmarshalling a JSON object to a slice. Update the question with the error and the JSON text so we can help you further. You can get the JSON text by printing buf.String().

Answer (score 0):

I assume your json has as the most outer element an object, so it looks probably like `{"key": [{"type": "foo"}]}`.

But you try to unmarshal into an array so it's expected to look like `[{"type": "foo"}]`.

To be sure you would have to post an example of your json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, following the advice from this answer (link below) I was able to figure out the correct json structure and I was missing a tier in the struct declaration.

[Golang issue with accessing Nested JSON Array after Unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377907/golang-issue-with-accessing-nested-json-array-after-unmarshalling)

```
// fixed
type Result struct {
    Features []struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
        .
        .
        .
```